# Find drop location in finder from my application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, finder

My Application has a file list and I want to drag a file name from it and drop it to the finder. After that, I would be able to transfer that dragged file to the finder. The problem I am facing is that how to get the drop location in the finder? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How did you implement the drag?

Comment: to transfer files from finder to my application, I register the data types that it can accept by invokingregisterForDraggedTypes and use concludeDragOperation to fetch URLs dragged into my application. But I want a solution for transferring files from my Application to finder, I know which files are dragged but how to get the drop location at finder?

Comment: `registerForDraggedTypes` and `concludeDragOperation` are methods for accepting dragged items. How do you start the drag?

Comment: yes, they are for accepting dragged items. I want to do the opposite drag items from my app and add them to the finder and I want to know how to do that.

Comment: Google found a tutorial at raywenderlich.com: [Drag and Drop Tutorial for macOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136272/drag-and-drop-tutorial-for-macos). Combine this tutorial with `NSFilePromiseProvider`. `NSFilePromiseProvider` isn't documented, read the comments in NSFilePromiseProvider.h.

Comment: Thanks, Willeke. I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `NSFilePromiseProvider`. Here the link to the WWDC talk: [What's New in Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/203/?time=1454)